# Why does pandas groupby pass only the first row to apply()?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe containing a couple of blank columns to be filled in later and some actual data in the other columns. The top of the dataframe looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Otw.png).

I'm trying to do a groupby and return an entirely new dataframe row-by-row i.e. for each group, I do some manipulation and return a row, and all of these rows get concatenated into a dataframe. This is the code for my manipulation function:

```
def get_trade_text(single_trade):
    single_trade.sort_values('Expiry', ascending=False, inplace=True)
    common_denominator = np.gcd.reduce(single_trade.Quantity)
    prem_diff = single_trade['CostBasis'].sum() / 100 / common_denominator
    ticker = single_trade.Symbol.values[0]
    exp = single_trade.Expiry.values[0]

    risk = calc_max_loss(single_trade)

    trade_text = ticker + ' ' + ' / '.join(single_trade.Expiry.dt.strftime('%b-%y')) + ' ' + \
                 ' / '.join(single_trade.Strike.astype(str)) + ' ' + ' / '.join(single_trade.Type) + ' Spread @ $' + \
                 '{:.2f}'.format(abs(prem_diff)) + ' ' + ('Debit' if prem_diff > 0 else 'Credit')

    return pd.Series([trade_text, prem_diff, exp, risk, ticker])
```

The `calc_max_loss` function returns a single float, so `risk` is a float value.

My issue is this: when I call this function on the table using `df.groupby('ID').apply(get_trade_text)`, I expect one row to be returned for every single ID. However, upon running this code, I see that it returns many rows, but all of them are the output for only the group where `ID == 1`. So the output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHIsz.png). Those are the rows I'd expect for an `ID` of 1, but none of the other IDs show up.

Things I've tried:

1) I rewrote the manipulation function to simply print out whatever is passed to it. Same problem. It prints out only the group relating to `ID == 1`.

2) I printed out the groups in the debugger using `df.groupby('ID').groups` and it shows up *correctly* i.e. it shows 76 groups (one for each ID) and each group has exactly the right indices inside its values.

3) I tried changing the column I'm using to group, and it has the exact same issue again i.e. if I do `df.groupby('Symbol').apply(get_trade_text)`, it creates groups from the `Symbol` column, arranges it alphabetically so `AAPL` is the first group, and then returns rows *only* for `AAPL` and not the other symbols.

I'm not sure why this could be happening. I've used `groupby` on much more complicated data frames and it's generally worked exactly as expected. But for this data, it seems to glitch out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please review [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the intro tour.  Your posted code is incomplete, and external references are generally not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

`single_trade.sort_values('Expiry', ascending=False, inplace=True)`

You are not supposed the edit the dataframe passed to apply in any way. It's supposed to work like a read only operation. Simply replacing this with:

`single_trade = single_trade.sort_values('Expiry', ascending=False)`

solves the problem.